# pyspark window function partitionBy limits to 1000 rows

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to use Pyspark windows functions, however my partitionBy seems to be limited to the first 1000 rows.

Current code:

```
window = Window.partitionBy(object_typesDF['object_type']).orderBy(article_typesDF['article_type'])
objectsDF = (object_typesDF.select(col('*'), row_number().over(window).alias('row_number')).where(col('row_number') <= 100))
```

.where() statement to limit my grouping to 100

.count() on the new dataFrame returns the correct number, however display() limits to 1000 results.

object_typesDF actually contains around 300k rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal, `display` is not a spark or python function. It is a function in your notebook environment. I believe you are using Zeppelin or Databricks.

If you want to retrieve all your data, then use `collect` but it will bring back a python object. You can use also `toPandas()` to work with a pandas datframe.